# UICollectionView Store cells in array for quick loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a question, I am not sure if it is possible, so I thought I would ask for advice on here!

I have an app, and it uses a UICollectionView to present a grid of buttons to the user.  I am using bootstrap-style gradient buttons, so to draw each cell (there can 40 buttons in one 'grid'), which uses some system resources, and redrawing can take some time (well - up to half a second!). The user can load different sets into the collection view as well.  In order to circumvent this loading time, would it be possible to hold all of the cells in an array, and instead of configuring each cell when -cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, simply pull the cell from the array?

I am not too sure if this is the done thing. My app has a loading screen, so the array can be populated at startup.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use NSCache to hold the drawn cells,

**1) @property(nonatomic, strong) NSCache *myCache;**

**2)** in viewDidLoad,

**self.myCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];**

**3)** use these 2 methods,

```
-(id) cellForIndexPathRow:(NSNumber *) number{
    return [self.myCache objectForKey:number];
}

-(void) setCell:(id) cell forIndexPathRow:(NSNumber *) number{
    [self.myCache setObject:cell forKey:number];
}
```

**4) When you draw the cell,**

first call

```
id cell = [self cellForIndexPathRow:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
if(!cell){
 //then create draw the cell

 //store the drawn cell in cache     
 [self setCell:cell forIndexPathRow:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Comment: I have another question - is there a way to make this multidimensional? I am thinking to possibly create as many caches as required and then adding them to an array? Unfortunately there would be a dynamic amount, otherwise I could just declare them in the .h file.

Comment: You can keep one cache object for them all, you can have different keys.

Comment: Why doesn't this, when called from viewDidLoad, for example, "pre-cache" cells:

for (NSInteger i = 8; i < 17; i++) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
        [self setCell:[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath] forIndexPathRow:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]];
    }